# Is there a way to show/hide partway

Tags: jquery, toggle

I am wondering if there is a way to use jquery to Show/Hide part way.

Our team made [these pages](http://housing.ucsc.edu/guide/eight/)  that have a background image and then text in a div.  I want the div to slide to the side part way so the viewer can see the whole image.  The main thing is I still want the text to be able to come back so they can still read.. does that make since.  I got the div to hide all the way, but not partly (like 10px)

```
$("#welcome").click(function () {
      $(this).hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BeccaAlley/qBnLk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your website, I believe the simplest solution is to add `overflow:hidden` to the picture container (`#welcomepicture`), and then animate the left margin of the text div (`#welcome`).

```
$("#welcome").toggle("click", 
    function() {
        var left = $(this).outerWidth() - 10 + "px";

        $(this).animate({ "margin-left": "+=" + left }, 500);
    },
    function() {
        var left = $(this).outerWidth() - 10 + "px";

        $(this).animate({ "margin-left": "-=" + left }, 500);
    }
);
```

I was able to test that this technique does, in fact, work for your website (using Chrome developer tools), however, the above script may need some tweaking, as it is just an example starting point.

I hope this helps!